# What is the purpose of homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, group-homomorphism

I know that a mapping $\phi:A\to B$ is a homomorphism provided that $$\phi(A*B)=\phi(A)\times\phi(B)$$ where $*$ and $\times$ are two operators on the algebraic structures $A$ and $B$ respectively. In other words, these mappings preserves structure of the operations.

I am, however, trying to get a deeper understanding of homomorphism. If they preserve the structure, what does this mean? What can we do with this?

An extention of homomorphisms, are isomorphism in which the two structures can then be seen "as the same". I can see how this can be a powerful tool, but without explicitly knowing the one-to-one and onto properties, what can homomorphisms be used for in general?

Comment: This is like the group version of a linear transformation from linear algebra.  There's lots of interesting things you can talk about that you couldn't say without this modicum of structure.

Comment: First of all, there is a nice general language to talk about structures and morphisms, this is called category theory. As for the usefulness, it varies. Linear maps in linear algebra have many applications (see for example the google page rank algorithm), bounded linear operators on Hilbert spaces are fundamental in quantum mechanics.